# Switching to design XML mode and back does not revert view to previous state?

Tags: intellij-idea

I open Android XML layout file and my IDE layout looks like this.

[image]

When I switch to XML design mode, then all open tabs are closed so that design screen gets maximum of space.

[image]

However, when I return back to **XML text mode**, the no.1 and no.3 are not restored.

[image]

Is there a way to prevent this happening? I am not sure if this is IDEA's bug or this can be set in IDEA's settings.

Comment: You forgot to blur the Palette window and the Properties window ^^

Comment: @SalmanKhakwani This is the proper way to do when you show snapshots of someone else's project. ;)

Comment: Yeah, i was helping you in that. ^^

Answer (score 0):

Just double click on the current tab, when you return to **XML text mode**.
This is happening because your tab gets maximized while you switch to XML design mode.

Comment: Double click on the current tab name? As I did this and nothing happens. It's not full screen mode, it's just that tabs 1 and 3 retracts and were never restored.

Comment: Well, your screen shot looks maximized.

Comment: @sandalone And can i know the reason for voting this answer down ?